# Mount NFS4 share as different user

Tags: nfs, nfs4, amazon-efs

I have an AWS EFS NFS4 share (`shareA`) that is mounted by some servers where all files are owned by userA/uid=800. I'd like to mount that share onto the `b`-series servers, configured to look like userB/uid=900 owns all of the files. How can I do this?

[image: NFS clients with mountpoints]

Comment: You need idmapd.

Comment: How would I use idmapd for this? I have read that it only maps usernames, while NFS alters permissions based on numeric user IDs? And how do I get idmapd to only apply the mapping to this one share, and not to the other shares on the server?

Comment: Well, you didn't include that.

Answer (score 1):

The way NFS operates is that is wants UIDs/GIDs synchronized across all participants. Newer versions support mappings (with `idmapd`) of local deviations, but that's pretty much it.

Aside from working with ACLs, I fear that you are out of luck.